# Can I do margin calculations in ddply()?

Tags: r, plyr

The `cast()` function is great at calculating margins for aggregate values:

`cast(df, IDx1+IDx2~IDy1, margins=c('IDx1','IDx2','grand_row'),c(min, mean, max))`

The problem is that I need to weight my means using a second vector and a custom function.

Of course, `ddply()` lets me apply custom aggregation functions to my grouped records:

```
ddply(d, IDx1+IDx2~IDy1 , function(x) 
c(
min(x$value),
MyFancyWeightedHarmonicMeanFunction(x$value,x$weight),
max(x$value)
)
)
```

...and this is awesome.

But what would really save the day is the ability to do both things at once, whether by calling the two-vector function in `cast()` or by faking somehow the `margins=()` variable in `ddply().`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty to compute the margins yourself:

```
ddply(d, "IDX1", ...) 
ddply(d, c("IDX1", "IDX2"), ...)
ddply(d, "IDy1", ...)
```

and then combine the results together with `rbind`.  It wouldn't be too hard to wrap this up into a general function.

Also, I'd rewrite your original code as:

```
ddply(d, IDx1+IDx2~IDy1, summarise, 
  min = min(value),
  wt.mean = MyFancyWeightedHarmonicMeanFunction(value, weight),
  max = max(value)
)
```

Comment: Hadley,
Thanks for the tip. The separate ddply operations, rbinded together, is exactly what I've done. Still getting my head around both summarise and transform.

Comment: `rbind.fill` is particularly helpful when ddply returns data frames with different numbers of columns.